# Rails missing template for JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my application controller I have a method where I'm trying to render a specific JS file located in the folder **lib/assets/api/v1/**

```
lib = render_to_string File.join(Rails.root,"/lib/assets/api/v1/shasync.js")

render :text => lib
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following **MissingTemplate** error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template Users/name/Projects/project/lib/assets/api/v1/shasync.js with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/name/Projects/project/app/views"
* "/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
* "/Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/shopify_app-6.2.0/app/views"):
```

Can anyone help please? I did this in the past and it worked, don't know why it's not working anymore.

Comment: Look at the end of your error message. It's not searching in the folder that you have it in. Try putting it in somewhere in `/Users/name/Projects/project/app/views`.

Comment: Could you please show us the entire action and give some more context of your log - starting from `GET ...`